# Где можно почитать про ORM Django?

Tags: django, django-orm

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста источники из которых можно научиться основам ORM Django.(Литература, статьи, сайты и т.д)

Comment: Логично, что в официальной документации https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/

Comment: Большое спасибо! )